# Repelling ferromagnetic materials with alternating fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

**Is it possible, through the induction of eddy currents, to repel a ferromagnetic material using an alternating magnetic field?**

Is there a frequency where if one were to spin a strong magnet close to a piece of iron, where it would be repelled by the changing magnetic field? Or no matter the velocity the magnetic permeability will always make the piece attracted to it.

Comment: Wouldn't it just cancel it out? At most? For no force either way?

Comment: This is also a possibility. I was interested how when you move a magnet close to a copper/aluminium they get "binded". Like if you drop the magnet it will brake, and if you move on top it will drag. If it makes sense I'm asking if there's a frequency that through histereses a ferromagnetic material acts almost like a paramagnetic one. If so, I will edit the description of the question to reflect that.